# Sending keys to inactive window?

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, sendkeys

I want to send keys like "a", not keystrokes like Shift in my application, which is something like On-Screen Keyboard. I used this code but it is not working:

```
IntPtr p = FindWindow(null, <myWindowTitle>);
ShowWindow(GetWindow(p, 3), 5);
SendKeys.SendWait("a");
```

but still I cannot send keys to the previous window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is actually nothing like the On-Screen Keyboard. It sends the keystrokes to the *active* window. Note that the OSK can never actually receive the input focus, and that's entirely by design.

`SendKeys` only sends input to the active window. In the Windows UI model, that's the only window that can receive keyboard/mouse input. That's the whole point of having the 'active'/'focused' window distinction in the first place.

It's difficult to propose an alternative solution to your problem without knowing precisely what you're trying to accomplish. Some ideas:

- There's no reason to re-implement the OSK; it's bundled with all versions of Windows, so you can simply start it with `Process.Start` and be certain that all will work fine.
- If you *do* need to do something like this yourself, look into copying its design and preventing your input window from ever receiving the focus. This will force the window that is to receive the keyboard events to maintain the focus and allow it to receive that input.
- Alternatively, you could call the [`SetForegroundWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) to activate the window that is to receive the keyboard input, but I don't recommend this.

Comment: Yes precisely i am making a On-screen keyboard, so i want to send keys to inactive window which will be activated if my application minimizes. how should i do this? Process.Start is not relevant to this issue, and SetForegroundWindow function is only making it harder, because using GetWindow is a bit simpler. thanks

Comment: @Peyman: `Process.Start` is the most relevant thing in the world here. The code you're looking for is `Process.Start("osk.exe")`. As I mentioned, Windows includes an on-screen keyboard application in all versions. You can rely on it being there, and rely on it working. Don't reinvent the wheel. Your comment just restates what the question does; I've already explained why that isn't going to work.

Comment: sorry but i really do not realize what should i do to send keys to the previous active window, lets suppose i want to develop an On-Screen Keyboard precisely. how Process.Start("osk.exe"); can help me do this?

Comment: @Peyman: It gives you an on-screen keyboard. Problem solved. As I indicated in my answer, you can't send keys to the *previously* active window, you can only send them to the *active* window. You have to make it active first. `SetForegroundWindow` is a way of doing that. Using the built-in OSK application is an even better solution.

Comment: a question, when i read your answer with more attention, i mentioned you are describing a situation when i want to send keys to my own application, nonetheless i want to send them to the previous active window as this piece of code demonstrates, ShowWindow(hwnd, 5); will show and activate the window with hwnd handler and GetWindow(hwnd, 3); will return the hwnd of previous active window rather than current active app.

Comment: Ok, i am agree that SendKeys.SendWait(string); will send keys to foreground application, this is the reason i am trying to activate the previous activate window first. to exemplify if notepad was foreground before my application became foreground, previous active app is notepad so first i activate notepad again, and then i send keys to the foreground app. this is the point i wonder why my code wont work?

Comment: @Peyman: I'm not assuming anything about which application you're using. That's completely irrelevant. It's a fundamental rule of Windows that you can't send input to inactive windows. Activate the other window first. I have no idea what that code shows or what point you're making. Hmm, from your second comment, it appears that the entire question here has changed. No matter, same answer. Call `SetForegroundWindow` to activate the window of interest. `GetWindow` retrieves the handle; pass that to `SetForegroundWindow`. Reading the documentation for these functions would be *very* helpful.

Comment: i cannot undrestand!!! my question is brief i put my code and i said in the last line : "but still I cannot send keys to the previous window" so i mentioned that i dont want to send keys to my own applications.