# Send keyboard input to cerain inactive window

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I send key press messages to certain inactive window. I tried to use PostMessage but no results.

Tried to test it on Notepad, message was successfully sent but no input in edit box.

I want to send it to certain window, not control, and can't do it globally (i want window to stay inactive).

Note: Window i want to receive input is game.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending keys to inactive window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206565/sending-keys-to-inactive-window)

Comment: No, I don't want to create On-screen keyboard. I want to make macro that will do certain actions on inactive window (I want to use other application in the same time). But what I read in linked question is that it looks like it is impossible? I recently I found macro application that did the same.

Comment: The only way to do it reliably is to generate actual input, for reasons described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx). Many programs try to cheat this, with varying levels of success that will never reach 100%.